# The file must be a file of type: pdf, doc, docx in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

When I want to upload pdf or ms word files I get this error:

The file must be a file of type: pdf, doc, docx

this is my controller:

```
public function store(BookRequest $request)
{
      $book = new Book();
    $book->title = $request->input('title');
    $book->isbn = $request->input('isbn');
    $book->$author = $request->input('author');
    $book->$description = $request->input('description');
    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $fileName = date('Y') . "_" . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $distination_path = 'books/';
        $file->move($distination_path, $fileName);
        $book->book_path = $distination_path . $fileName;
    }
        $book->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $book->save();
    return redirect('/library')->with('message','کتاب موفقانه آپلود شد.')->withErrors('مشکل رخداد');
}
```

And the Request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'=>'required',
        'author'=>'required',
        'isbn'=>'required',
        'file'=>'required|mimes:pdf,doc,docx',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the exact `rules`  in correct model ?

Comment: Solved it.It was a mistake on lines 6,7

Comment: Can you post how  you solved in answer, Coz it might be useful for future readers

Comment: See line 6 and 7 you can find ($)

Comment: Rastager, That's great, i too missed that ;) I have added it as answer to make this Question Fulfill !

Comment: You shall accept it if you think :)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question (As it might made the Question fulfill)

Remove the `$` from `$author` and `$description`

i.e., Change the below code to

```
$book->$author = $request->input('author');
$book->$description = $request->input('description');
```

like this

```
$book->author = $request->input('author');
$book->description = $request->input('description');
```

Hope, it will helpful for future readers